# Usage of layout in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to create this layout for this plot:

```
layout(matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,
                2,2,2,3,3,3,
                2,2,2,3,3,3,
                2,2,2,3,3,3), nrow=4,ncol=6,byrow = TRUE))

# Set up the top chart that keeps track of the current frame/iteration
# Dress it up a little just for fun
plot(-5, xlim = c(1997,2011), ylim = c(0, .3), xlab = "", ylab = "", main = "Time",axes=F)
abline(v=1995, lwd=5, col = rgb(0, 0, 255, 255, maxColorValue=255))

# Bring back the X axis
xticks <- 1997:2011
axis(side=1, at=xticks, labels=xticks)

# Plot
plot(1:100,1:100)
plot(1:100,1:100)
```

Obviously the last two plot aren't  `plot(1:100,1:100)`in my real code, but I have a question on usage of `layout`. Why i get this error on the first plot?

```
Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
```

I want the first picture to have a little height

Comment: so you are only using the first plot to get some extra space on top?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might sound silly, but the reason is indeed that the figure margins are too large!

Let me elaborate on this. In R, there are several kind of margins to let your pictures breath:

[image: Image credithttp://research.stowers-institute.org/mcm/efg/R/Graphics/Basics/mar-oma/index.htm]

In your particular case, the margins are eating all the space available, as you try to cram too many figures in the same plot.

To solve this, I would advise to set all the margins to 0:

```
par(mai=c(0,0,0,0), oma=c(0,0,0,0), mar=c(0,0,0,0))
```

Which will likely result in your plot to at least be rendered. At the same time, all the subplots will be way too close to each other, so you then have to increase the margins little by little, with similar calls to `par(...)` until the results looks fine.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

The margins are measured in multiples of line-heights via the parameters `par(mar)`, `par(oma)`, and `par(mai)`, as described in this passage in `?par`

> `MAR`
>
> A numerical vector of the form c(bottom, left, top, right) which gives the number of lines of margin to be specified on the four sides of the plot. The default is c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1.

There are two solutions, you can (a) reduce the margins by setting one of the previous 'par()' settings or (b) you can increase the size of the device, either by re-sizing the device using the mouse if it's a visible device, or if you are printing to PDF, for example, you can set the device size to be larger by setting height and width parameters when you set up the device, as in:

```
pdf( <<FileNameHere>> , width = par('din')[1],height = par('din')[2] )
```

I by setting width to `par('din')[1]` and height to `par('din')[2]`, you get a PDF with the same dimensions as the current device, which lets you make adjustments to the visible device with the mouse.  (This is handy for one-off plots and poor practice for a production environment)

If you do reduce the margins, I recommend not setting `mar=c(0,0,0,0)`, as that will result in not having visible axis labels.